# How can I get the current user roles from Spring security 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have loaded the roles from the database for the current user. And I can access the user role with spring security expression in JSP, and can hide the options and URLs which are not authorized with hasRole. Now I wanted to have it in the servlet and display it in the logs (or store in the user object session). How can we achieve it?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```

You have the collection of roles in the authorities variable.

Comment: you should use the grantedauthority interface in this list as the implementation can differ between authoritization providers

Comment: If you do this there will be an unchecked case but you can avoid this by having the collection type as: Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>

Answer (score 45):

If you develop on Java 8, it's getting easier.

To get all user roles:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

Set<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
     .map(r -> r.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

To check if the user has a particular role, for example, *ROLE_USER*:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

boolean hasUserRole = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
          .anyMatch(r -> r.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER"));
```

Comment: I tried your solution but It is getting the value from "authorties" , not the "role"
and my  code is:
     auth.jdbcAuthentication() .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(enc)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select USERNAME, role, authorities from vwuserrole where USERNAME=?")
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select USERNAME, PASSWORD, 1 as enabled  from vwuser where USERNAME=?")

I don't understand how authorities and role should be manipulated.

Comment: Ok, I searched and find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525380/difference-between-role-and-grantedauthority-in-spring-security
But I still puzzled why the role value is empty. with the query I put.

Answer (score 7):

Try to call [getUserPrincipal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) from HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i didn't try it, but i have implemented what Dani told, it worked for me.

Comment: Fair enough. Juts a quick note: Dani's approach have drawback of coupling your code with Spring security implementation while getUserPricipal() is standard call in servlet specification and should work with any provider.

Comment: With getUserPrincipal() you only get the name of the requestor. I think question is how to get the roles assigned to that user, so I guess in getUserPrincipal() wont work that way also.

Comment: HttpServletRequest is applicable to a web module only.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a custom `hasRole` function for my project.

```
public static boolean hasRole (String roleName)
{
    return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream()
            .anyMatch(grantedAuthority -> grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals(roleName));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete both answers...

Here is a Spring security implementation of `getUserPrincipal`, so you can see that the `getUserPrincipal` actually is  `SecurityContextHolder`

```
public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
    Authentication auth = getAuthentication();

    if ((auth == null) || (auth.getPrincipal() == null)) {
        return null;
    }
    return auth;
}

// And the getAuthentication
private Authentication getAuthentication() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (!trustResolver.isAnonymous(auth)) {
        return auth;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone.

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getHomePage(Authentication authentication, Model model) {
        User u = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        model.addAttribute("cu", u);
        return "sb/homePage";
    }
```

And in template Thymeleaf:

```
Current user:</br>
    <div th:if="${cu}">
        Username: [[${cu.username}]]</br>
        Password: [[${cu.password}]]</br>
        Role: [[${cu.authorities[0]}]]</br>
        Enabled: [[${cu.enabled}]]</br>
        Full: [[${cu}]]</br>
    </div>
    <div th:unless="${cu}">
        Not logged-in!
    </div>
```