# sec:authorize don't work in the thymeleaf code with hasRole method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my current spring-boot project, the header for my views have the following instruction:

```
<a sec:authorize="hasRole('admin')" th:href="@{/home}">...</a>
```

which is not working when I run the application and open the view in the browser (even when the user has the role). In the same view, I also use `sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"` and `sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"`, both working fine. In my java code, I have some methods with this annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
```

which working fine, too. Why this is not working in the view? Anyone can tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Because you must add a "ROLE_" before your rolename.

Like this:

```
sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_admin')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ROLE_` prefix should not be necessary as of Spring 3 I believe.

Try using `hasAuthority('admin')` instead of `hasRole()`. The difference between the two is descriped in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525380/difference-between-role-and-grantedauthority-in-spring-security) post