# Jhipster: How do I add an extra field to user identity for authentication?

Tags: jhipster

I'm working on a project based on Jhipster that requires the use of an additional field (`organization`) to uniquely identify a user during authentication. So we can have two rows in the `JHI_USER` table with the same `login` and `password` but  different `organization`s and this should represent two separate users.

I searched in code but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for previous answer, I really don`t understand you last time. 
In this case you can use OPERATIONS(OR ANOTHER ROLE) and you can check if user has two roles like ["ROLE_USER", "OPERATION_ORGANIZATION_1"] then do something, but if user has ["ROLE_USER", "OPERATION_ORGANIZATION_1"] then another action.
You must add concept "operation". I wrote about it here:
[Jhipster - roles and operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638777/4871485)

It`s different, that what you want, but it's specific exit from your situation.