# Spring Security Domain Model Authorization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Spring Security has this basic idea of a Principal and GrantedAuthority. I've implemented Spring Security and read this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525380/difference-between-role-and-grantedauthority-in-spring-security) and understand at a basic level that a "ROLE" is nothing more than a GrantedAuthority prefixed with "ROLE_".

What I don't understand is why have this convention in the first place? Why have `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('XYZ')")` be equivilant to `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_XYZ')")`?

What's so special about segregating Granted Authorities like this? What's the purpose?

Additionally, what is the best convention for applying these "ROLES" to specific instances of a Domain Model. Take for example a system that keeps track of projects and you want to explicitly give users access to view and edit certain projects. I could create ROLE_EDIT_PROJECT and ROLE_VIEW_PROJECT but that's application-wide. Where would you make the relationship of a ROLE to a specific project? A join table? Would you even involve Spring Security into this or build this type of security from scratch within your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unfortunately don't know why this convention is used, probably just legacy code I would guess.

For the second part of your question, I would suggest using "hasPermission(project, 'view')" and define your own [PermissionEvaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-method-built-in).

more information can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html)