# What is the difference between hasRole() and hasAuthority() in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

assume that I have an user who has following authentication:

```
 List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
 grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("READ_PRODUCT"));
 grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("WRITE_PRODUCT"));

 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("usr", "pwd", grantedAuthorities));
```

In the security check, I should check if the user has the right authority to access the API. I did the following to achive it:

```
 http
    .httpBasic().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/product/**").hasAuthority("READ_PRODUCT");
```

Here I use `hasAuthority()` to check if the user has the right authority, but I found that there is also a method called `hasRole()` but I dont know that is the difference between these two methods? Can anyone explain me the difference and if I want to use `hasRole()` here, how can I use it here? I tried to replace `hasAuthority()` by `hasRole()` but it was not successful

Comment: The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525380/difference-between-role-and-grantedauthority-in-spring-security) question may help you.

Comment: In your case `hasRole()` does not apply, because your authorities are not prefixed with "ROLE_". If you have an authority e.g "ROLE_USER", then `hasRole("USER")` is equivalent to `hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")`. In your case, for the authority "READ_PRODUCT", there is no equivalent role.

Comment: ah I see, thank you very much @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana

Answer (score 4):

`hasRole()` defines the Role (for Example: "Employee" or "Visitor"), while
`hasAuthority()` defines the Rights (for Example: One Employee can only use the Main Door, but another one can also use the Backdoor