# Cannot get roles working in Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have spent days on trying to get **ROLES** working within Spring Security using *JWT tokens*. Authentication seems to work fine but *authorization* seems to still not be working.

My current setup is that I have...

- an In Memory Database for Users (I have one single user called "lion", and one single role "KING")
- an authenticate end point which authenticates the user, and returns the JWT in the response.

My **WebCofig** looks like this :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling()
        .and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I Basically want to say

- anyone can access (/)
- anyone can access "hello" and "authenticate"

My web controller looks like this :

```
@Controller
public class WebController {  

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    @ResponseBody  
    public String hello() {  
        return "Hello! ALL USERS logged in or not are allowed to see this!";  
    }  

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('KING')")
    @RequestMapping("/king")  
    @ResponseBody  
    public String king() {  
        return "Hello King";  
    } 

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_KING')")
    @RequestMapping("/king2")  
    @ResponseBody  
    public String king2() {  
        return "Hello King2";  
    } 
}
```

My web token returned via my authentication looks good (i think..). Decoded the body looks like this :

```
{
  "sub": "lion",
  "scopes": "KING",
  "iat": 1580645802,
  "exp": 1580663802
}
```

... and will allow me to access anywhere where I just need to be authenticated. "anyRequest().authenticated()".

However both king and king2 REST endpoints give me **403 - "Access Denied"** even though my user has role **KING** (I tried both KING and ROLE_KING)

I feel like I am missing a piece of the puzzle.

My JWT Filter seems to look good too. The authentication object (..which is set in the security context handler like so : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);) has exactly ONE SimpleGrantedAuthority with role = KING.

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    String username = null;
    String jwt = null;

    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);

        username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
    }

    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

            userDetails.getAuthorities(); //has exactly ONE SimpleGrantedAuthority with value "KING"

            SimpleGrantedAuthority s = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("asfd");

            s.getAuthority(); //string


            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = jwtUtil.getAuthentication(jwt,
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), userDetails);

            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            logger.info("authenticated user " + username + ", setting security context");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

My UserDetailsService looks like this :

```
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordValidationService passwordValidationService;

    @Override
    public User loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserEntity u = repository.findByUserNameIgnoreCase(userName);

        SimpleGrantedAuthority a = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(u.getRole().toString());

        ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> auths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        auths.add(a);

        return new User(u.getUserName(), u.getPassword(), auths);
    }
}
```

Everything looks good to me which is why I am confused right now :(

*********** UPDATE ************

If I use **hasAuthority** instead of **hasRole** then this works :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('KING')")
@RequestMapping("/king3")  
@ResponseBody  
public String king3() {  
    return "Hello King";  
}
```

So how do I get **hasRole** to work? Am I missing the appending of "ROLE_" somewhere in my code?

Comment: It could be that when `JwtRequestFilter` has completed, the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is invoked since it matches on any other URL as well. Can you check that?

Comment: can you try `hasAuthority('KING')`?

Comment: yes that works!! :) So how do I make KING a Role, and not an Authority?

Comment: It sounds like your `UserDetailService` implementation is loading Authorities instead of Roles. Please add the code for that in your question. Also, please add all code as formatted text instead of images.

Comment: OK I have updated the code. UserDetails can only load authorities and it can't load roles. If I look at the interface there is only this method: getAuthorities()

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot / Spring Security are you using?

Comment: spring-security-core-5.2 and spring-core-5.1

Comment: Starting with Spring Security 4, hasRole('KING') is equivalent to hasAuthority('ROLE_KING'). Correspondingly, in the role association (in database/LDAP) should be ROLE_KING. Please check for it in your actual role association, whether 'ROLE_' is pre-pended or not. A good discussion is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525380/difference-between-role-and-grantedauthority-in-spring-security

Comment: Could this be a conceptual problem? Are you aware, that OAuth2 has only the notion of scopes that could be checked (with the now deprecated spring-security-oauth library) with @Preauthorize("oauth2.hasScope('FOO')").
This has now moved to spring-security, and can be checked with @Preauthorize(''hasAuthority('SCOPE_FOO')") with 'FOO' being the granted scope from the jwt.

Comment: As there are only scopes in OAuth2, I suppose they are mapped from the received jwt by Spring Security to Authorities without doing any mapping to roles.