# Spring Security 3.x.x - FilterChain doesn't work but @PreAuthorize works only

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final LoginService loginService;
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(cs -> cs.disable())
                .sessionManagement(s->s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .formLogin(f->f.disable())
                .httpBasic(h->h.disable());
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->{
////                    auth.requestMatchers("/lectures/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
////                    auth.requestMatchers("/instructors/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
//                    auth.requestMatchers("/instructors/**").authenticated()
//                                    .requestMatchers("/lectures/**").permitAll()
////                        .requestMatchers("/instructors/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER")
//                            .requestMatchers("/admins/**").permitAll()
//                            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
//auth.requestMatchers("/instructors/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                    auth.anyRequest().permitAll()

                    ;
                });
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(loginService);
        return new ProviderManager(provider);
    }


    @Bean
    public LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
        return new LoginSuccessHandler(jwtService, adminRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public LoginFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
        return new LoginFailureHandler();
    }


    @Bean
    public CustomJsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customJsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
        CustomJsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customJsonUsernamePasswordLoginFilter
                = new CustomJsonUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(objectMapper);
        customJsonUsernamePasswordLoginFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        customJsonUsernamePasswordLoginFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(loginSuccessHandler());
        customJsonUsernamePasswordLoginFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(loginFailureHandler());
        return customJsonUsernamePasswordLoginFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationProcessingFilter jwtAuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
        JwtAuthenticationProcessingFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtAuthenticationProcessingFilter(jwtService, adminRepository);
        return jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String NO_CHECK_URL = "/login";

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;

    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper = new NullAuthoritiesMapper();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getRequestURI().equals(NO_CHECK_URL)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String refreshToken = jwtService.extractRefreshToken(request)
                .filter(jwtService::isTokenValid)
                .orElse(null);

        if (refreshToken != null) {
            checkRefreshTokenAndReIssueAccessToken(response, refreshToken);
            return;
        }

        if (refreshToken == null) {
            checkAccessTokenAndAuthentication(request, response, filterChain);
        }
    }

    public void checkRefreshTokenAndReIssueAccessToken(HttpServletResponse response, String refreshToken) {
        adminRepository.findByRefreshToken(refreshToken)
                .ifPresent(admin -> {
                    String reIssuedRefreshToken = reIssueRefreshToken(admin);
                    jwtService.sendAccessAndRefreshToken(response, jwtService.createAccessToken(admin.getEmail()),
                            reIssuedRefreshToken);
                });
    }

    private String reIssueRefreshToken(Admin admin) {
        String reIssuedRefreshToken = jwtService.createRefreshToken();
        admin.updateRefreshToken(reIssuedRefreshToken);
        adminRepository.saveAndFlush(admin);
        return reIssuedRefreshToken;
    }

    public void checkAccessTokenAndAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                  FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("checkAccessTokenAndAuthentication() 호출");
        jwtService.extractAccessToken(request)
                .filter(jwtService::isTokenValid)
                .ifPresent(accessToken -> jwtService.extractEmail(accessToken)
                        .ifPresent(email -> adminRepository.findByEmail(email)
                                .ifPresent(this::saveAuthentication)));
        log.info("saveAuthentication() 호출");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void saveAuthentication(Admin myAdmin) {
        String password = myAdmin.getPassword();

        UserDetails userDetailsUser = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.builder()
                .username(myAdmin.getEmail())
                .password(password)
                .roles(myAdmin.getRole().name())
                .build();

        Authentication authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetailsUser, null,
                        authoritiesMapper.mapAuthorities(userDetailsUser.getAuthorities()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/instructors")
@RestController
public class InstructorController {

    private final InstructorService instructorService;

    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_MANAGER')")//it works
    public ResponseEntity createInstructor(@Valid @RequestBody InstructorPostDto instructorPostDto) {
        InstructorResponseDto createdInstructor = instructorService.createInstructor(instructorPostDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdInstructor, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.hh99'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // security 관련 의존성
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // jwt 관련 의존성
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:4.2.1'
}

tasks.named('bootBuildImage') {
    builder = 'paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Hi I'm trying to apply Spring Security+JWT on my small application
and I wanted that only 'MANAGER' can access to /lectures,/instructors
but even though user has MANAGER authorization, they couldn't access to them
so I changed hasAnyRole("MANAGER") to permitAll() and applied @PreAuthorized on Controller, and then it works
maybe the order of filters or just problem of code..
can anyone help me??

Comment: `JwtAuthenticationProcessingFilter ` is some sort of home made security, using JWTs as sessions is not recommended. Why are you building some home made security using spring security, and not using the standards that are implemented in the library? JWTs should not be used as sessions

Comment: I declared the oreder of filters, and it worked
it was dumb mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this

1. You may use hasAuthority instead of hasRole

   `auth.requestMatchers("/lectures/**").hasAuthority("MANAGER")`
2. Authorities should prefix role with the "ROLE_". You may modify getAuthorities() method in your entity class extending org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails class as follows

   ```
   @Override
   public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
       return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+role.name()));
   }
   ```

[difference-between-role-and-grantedauthority-in-spring-security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542316) here is the link which has explained this concept in detail.